# One liner for creating several deep copies of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-copy

In initializing my code, I need to create several numpy arrays all of the same shape.  It's straightforward to do

```
>>> nx=10
>>> ny=10
>>> a = np.zeros((ny,nx))
>>> b = np.copy(a)
>>> c = np.copy(a)
>>> d = np.copy(a)
>>> etc.
```

but it is certainly tedious.  I was hoping there might be a one-liner to do this.  I tried

```
>>> (b,c,d,e,f,g) = 6*[np.copy(a)]
```

but that gives me several *references* to `a`, not independent copies.

Is there something similar that will give independent copies?

Comment: `b,c,d,e,f,g = [np.copy(a) for _ in range(6)]`?

Comment: Use @user3483203's suggestion: `a, b, c, d = np.zeros((4, nx, ny))`

Comment: Be careful when using unpacking with an iterable.  Unpacking does not tolerate a mismatch in lengths.  Don't use it just to avoid a few editing steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take advantage of tuple unpacking here. If you're creating a standard Numpy array (zeros, ones, eye, etc.) then you can do it by setting the outermost value of the shape to the number of copies you'd like:

```py
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = np.zeros((7, ny, nx))
```

Be aware that if you create your "copies" this way, they're actually all slices into the same array.

If you would actually like to make copies of a particular array (and not operate on slices of one larger array), you should unpack a generator expression of calls to `np.copy`

```py
# a is the numpy array to be copied
b, c, d, e, f, g = (np.copy(a) for _ in range(6))
```

Make sure that the number of copies being made (6 or 7 in the examples above) is accurate.

Comment: A potential disadvantage of the first option is memory leakage as if say, b,c,d,e,f,g go out of scope with only a remaining none of the actual data gets freed.